# What $A := \{ \mathbb{R} \setminus (0, \frac{1}{n}) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ means?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show how such a set would look: $\bigcup A$, where $A := \{ \mathbb{R} \setminus (0, \frac{1}{n}) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. As far as I understand $\bigcup A$ (which is an union of a family of sets) is equal to $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{R}  \setminus (0,  \frac{1}{n+1})}$, so the final set would look like this: $ \bigcup A = \{ \{ \mathbb{R} \setminus 0\} \cup \{ \mathbb{R} \setminus 1\} \cup \{ \mathbb{R} \setminus \frac{1}{2}\} \cup \ldots \}$. Am I correct?

Comment: In standard English usage, one can say either "What such a set would look like" or "How such a set would look", but _not_ "How such a set would look like". The second form "How it would look", is sometimes construed as "How good it would look", and sometimes that expression should be avoided if that is not what you meant.

Comment: Corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is a set of sets.

$$ A \stackrel{\text{def}}{=\!=} \left\{ \mathbb{R} \setminus \left(0, \frac{1}{n}\right) \;\bigg|\;n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \tag{51} $$

Means the same thing as

$$ A = \left\{ \bigg( -\infty, 0 \bigg] \bigcup \left[ \frac{1}{n}, \infty \right) \bigg|\; \mathbb{n} \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \tag{52} $$

So, let's figure out what $\cup A$ is.

Note that $x \in \cup A$ if any only if there is at least one element $S\in A$ such that $x \in S$ (101).

$$ x \in \cup A \iff \exists S \in A \mathop. x \in S $$

Suppose we have an arbitrary real number $x$ .

Suppose $x \le 0$, then $x$ is in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \left( 0, \frac{1}{1} \right) $ (i.e. the element of $A$ where $n = 1$).

Suppose $x \ge 1$, then $x$ is in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \left( 0, \frac{1}{1} \right)$.

Now we're left with the cases where $x$ is in the open interval $(0,1)$ .

We know that $x$ is less than or equal to $\lfloor x \rfloor$ , which means that $\frac{1}{x}$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ (101).

$$ x \le \lfloor x \rfloor \implies \frac{1}{x} \ge \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \tag{101} $$

This means that $x$ is an element of the element of $A$ associated with $n=\lfloor x \rfloor$ (102).

$$ x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left( 0, \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \right) \tag{102} $$

This fact is more obvious if I write it out the same way I did in (52).

$$ x \in \left(\;\; \bigg( -\infty, 0\bigg] \cup \left[ \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}, \infty \right)\;\; \right) \tag{103} $$

Therefore

$$ \cup A = \mathbb{R} $$

Answer (score 1):

I would write 
$$\bigcup A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \big(\mathbb R\setminus(0,1/n)\big)$$
and use the definition of set subtraction. I think to write any more would be to hand you the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: Use the fact that $(R\cap A)\cup(R\cap B)=R\cap(A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 1):

I do no interpret it as a union of sets at all.

I interpret it as a set of a set of sets:

$A = \{\mathbb R\setminus (0,\frac 1n)|n\in\mathbb N\}=$

$\{\mathbb R\setminus (0,1); \mathbb R\setminus (0,\frac 12); \mathbb R \setminus (0, \frac 13); .........\}=$

$\{(-\infty,0]\cup [1, \infty);(-\infty,0]\cup [\frac 12, \infty); (-\infty,0]\cup [\frac 13, \infty), ...... \}$

In other words $A$ is *NOT* a subset of $\mathbb R$.  $A$ is a *set* of subsets of $\mathbb R$.  Each element in $\mathbb R$ is a subset of $A$,  and each element of $A$ is the set that is all of $\mathbb R$ except a small segment $(0, \frac 1n)$, or in other words, each element of $A$ is a union of $(-\infty,0]$ and $[\frac 1n, \infty)$..

Comment: And once you understand this, it might be a good moment to apply DeMorgan's laws to compute the *complement* of the union-over-A, which should be easy.